# How can I delete the L3 switch port configuration?

Tags: hp, hp-comware

I have HP 5500 L3 switch. I wanted to delete the particular port configuration and wanted to reconfigure it.

Since the command set is different from Cisco, can anyone help me?

Comment: One more thing I want to add, currently that port is configured as trunk port. I want to change it into the access port.
It is possible to convert trunk port to access port without restarting the switch.???

Comment: use the help facility.  the change you want to make is to the interface - you want to change the interface type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With later versions of ComWare you can use the default command on an interface.

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
[HP-GigabitEthernet1/0/1]default
This command will restore the default settings. Continue? [Y/N]:y
```

It should clear the port back to just **port link-mode bridge**.

If you have an older version of the OS you will need to use the **undo** command and negate the previous settings as the other guys mentioned.

Hope this helps you on your quest.

SleepyMan

Comment: Issue get resolved. `undo port trunk` this command work for me.

Answer (score 0):

actually I've got HP switches 2600 series and after writing "erase" and clicking "tab" button I see choices which I can make: erase config, flash, or start-up config.

But to erase configuration for only one port what about deleting this port (if it's logical only) and write setting again?

And I don't understand why you cannot try specific commands which you would like to erase with "no" commands: like 
"no ip address"
or 
"no auto-detect".

Last method is most common.
Unfortunnatelly no L3 swtich is close to me.

Comment: no ip address and no auto detect command hardly work with Comos 5. I have search on net but didn't find anything.

Comment: I don't remember Comware (5500) commands just offhand, but you negate command with "undo". With Procurve (2600) it's "no"... so for example if you add a tagged port to VLAN with "vlan 10 tagged 12" you negate it with "no vlan 10 tagged 12". Comware works the same way - "command" vs "undo command". Check the CLI references for details.

Comment: I know that  "no ip address" or "no auto-detect"." is not for this device, I only wanted to say that you can negate commands with "no" word guys

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Undo"

for example: while in the Gigabitethernet interface# Undo port access

Answer (score -1):

you can also change the port type to `port link-mode route` and back to `port link-mode bridge` and the port will be in its default state